# ASP MVC SimpleMembership and WebSecurity

Tags: asp.net-mvc, security, membership

im building a big app for a school project, separated in a few layers, being the presentation layer (the web server using asp mvc 4), logic and data layer.

Im kinda new to asp mvc, and im stuck with an idea about register/login mechanics. So far using the simplemembership and websecurity from the new project template seems really good. But here comes the problem: the above mentioned needs to connect to a database to do its job, while the web server wont be using the database directly, but the logic layer api methods to validate and create new users. What should i use to achieve a similar functionality as WebSecurity to manage all the login/register and session related stuff?

Comment: I don't quite understand your issue with WebSecurity. Is it the fact that it's connected to a database? Or the fact that the startup template embeds WebSecurity within the AccountController?

Comment: Its the fact that it needs a database, and the web server wont be using the db directly, but instead consuming web services from a logic layer.

Comment: So what i should actually do is implement a sort of webSecurity myself which uses web services instead of a db